# How do you properly implement a sound toggle in libgdx?

Tags: java, audio, libgdx

I'm currently using a button in the main menu as a toggle that sets a boolean value to true or false. It's initialized to true and if it's set to false, no sound will play.

However, the problem is that if you set the toggle to false in the main menu and switch screens to say, the play screen, and then back to the main menu again, it's initialized to true again because a new screen is being used.

What ways are there around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the value of the setting in a boolean field of a class instance that you keep around all the time. The button itself is a view object--do not rely on it to store your state.

For example, create a class called UserSettings and have a `soundEnabled` boolean in it. Your game instance can keep a reference to an instance of UserSettings to pass to all the different screens. When the MenuScreen is initialized, it looks at the `soundEnabled` boolean and uses that to set the initial checked state of the button. And the button has a ChangeListener that modifies the boolean in the UserSettings object appropriately.

Then in the play screen, the same UserSettings object is passed in and that's what it uses to determine whether sound should be on.

Furthermore, you can save the UserSettings object to a file (or preference) using the Json class, and then your game can load the one from the file (if it exists) when the game is reopened. This way, the users' preferences are remembered from session to session.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks for the answer!